# ngFor is duplicating tbody tag out of ngFor scoope

Tags: angular

I have the following table code:

```
<tbody>
  <div *ngFor="let lin of items | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: bus.page, totalItems:oResponse.total }" style="border: 1px dashed blue;">
     <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{lin.id}}">
        <td>{{lin.A}}</td> 
        <td>{{lin.B}}</td> 
        <td>{{lin.C}}</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3"> 
           <div id="{{lin.id}}" class="collapse in">
              <div>{{lin.D}}</div>                      
              <div>{{lin.E}}</div>
              <div>{{lin.F}}</div>
              <div>{{lin.G}}</div>
            </div>
          </td>
     </tr>
  </div>
</tbody>
```

I expected result is a table with a couple  per ngFor iteration, first one with A, B and C data, and second one with a single row with colspan 3 and all data request with the collapse behaviour.

The problem is a new  tag is created in each ngFor's iteration, so my table is completely broken. What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: using `ng-container` instead of `div`

Comment: Try using `ng-container` as Angular doesn't put it in the DOM. Check out [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) instead of `div` to maintain the table structure.

> The Angular ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

```
 <tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let lin of items | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: bus.page, totalItems:oResponse.total }" style="border: 1px dashed blue;">
     <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{lin.id}}">
        <td>{{lin.A}}</td> 
        <td>{{lin.B}}</td> 
        <td>{{lin.C}}</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3"> 
           <div id="{{lin.id}}" class="collapse in">
              <div>{{lin.D}}</div>                      
              <div>{{lin.E}}</div>
              <div>{{lin.F}}</div>
              <div>{{lin.G}}</div>
            </div>
          </td>
     </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer div element is misplaced (it cannot belong there).  Within the tbody you should only contain tr and not a div element.

You'll have to remove the div element from the table all together and move the attributes to the tr if you would like to repeat rows.